# Xamarin forms: Issue with special date selection in XamForms.Controls.Calendar

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am using `XamForms.Controls.Calendar` for marking events. The special dates are marked in yellow color.  If a date has more than 1 event, first I list all the events using a `DisplayActionSheet`. After that user can select an event from the `DisplayActionSheet`. Then the event detail page will show to the user. If the date has only one event it will directly load the event detail page when tapping on it.

My problem happening when the events titles have duplicate entries. So it will open all the event detail pages when selecting one item.

I have uploaded a sample project [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gvetCD65SuApGYSwdeiFMkSAEXVxUKKW/view?usp=sharing) for the reference. The special dates are marked in yellow color. If we click on Sep 18 or 25 it will open the event detail page. There are multiple events added for June 27. When clicking on the June 27 date, it will show the list of events using `DisplayActionSheet`. The first 3 events have the same title, if we click on any one from the first 3, it will open the 3 details page.

Code for opening Detail Page:

```
if (selectedEventsList.Count == 1)
{
    await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new DetailPage(selectedEventsList[0].title));
}
else
{
    eventTitleList.Clear();
    for (int j = 0; j < selectedEventsList.Count; j++)
    {
        eventTitleList.Add(selectedEventsList[j].title);
    }
    string action = await DisplayActionSheet(null, "Cancel", null, eventTitleList.ToArray());
    for (int k = 0; k < eventTitleList.Count; k++)
    {
        if (action == eventTitleList[k])
        {
            await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new DetailPage(eventTitleList[k]));
        }
    }
}
```

Here I am using the title field as the `DisplayActionSheet` entries. I think a lot to include the id check when clicking an item. But no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `title` of **events** is not the only .You could add a string (number index) to tag each options

```
private async void calendar_DateClicked(object sender, DateTimeEventArgs e)
        {
            int num = 0;
            var specialList = calendar.SpecialDates;
            var date = e.DateTime;
            selectedEventsList.Clear();
            foreach (SpecialDate specialDate in specialList)
            {
                if (specialDate.Date.Year == date.Year && specialDate.Date.Month == date.Month && specialDate.Date.Day == date.Day)
                {
                    events model = new events();
                    model = newEventsList[num];
                    selectedEventsList.Add(model);
                }
                num++;
            }

            if (selectedEventsList.Count == 1)
            {
                await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new DetailPage(selectedEventsList[0].title));
            }
            else
            {
                eventTitleList.Clear();
                for (int j = 0; j < selectedEventsList.Count; j++)
                {
                    eventTitleList.Add((j+1).ToString()+"."+selectedEventsList[j].title); // add the index to distinguish between items with same title .
                }
                string action = await DisplayActionSheet(null, "Cancel", null, eventTitleList.ToArray());
                for (int k = 0; k < eventTitleList.Count; k++)
                {
                    if (action == eventTitleList[k])
                    {
                        //opening new page with selected item
                        //if same titles are in the action list, it will open all the items
                        //I need to select the selcted item only
                        await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new DetailPage(selectedEventsList[k].title));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: I tried to add the event id with the title, but that is not a good way. Didn't think about adding a count for events, thanks.